# How to get gcc on Cygwin to define _WIN32?

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

Apparently newer versions of gcc on Cygwin no longer define `_WIN32`. Is there any easy way to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC allows you to define macros on the command line. The syntax would be

```
-D _WIN32
```

You could add this to `CFLAGS` in your makefile, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, but is there also a way to make it permanent (so that it stays defined every time)?

Comment: @Runemoro Well... you could write a wrapper script that passes its arguments to gcc and adds the `-D _WIN32` flag, and rename the actual gcc to something else, I suppose...